# Android Message Handler not receiving all messages I send

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, message-queue

I'm very new to Android programming and its associated messaging model, but I'm not getting the results I expect based on all the code examples I've seen.

I'm trying to pass messages from a thread back to the UI thread so I can update my UI.  The sample code below attempts to abstract the problem.  I have a handler in my UI that is set up to receive messages, and a thread class that sends a message with a counter, sleeps a second, increments the counter and sends another.  The problem is that I see the sender thread send messages that are never received.  Sometimes they are - and for a long run of messages.  Then a bunch are sent and lost.  Then they get received again.

A previous question implied that I should be using dispatchMessage rather than sendMessage - this actually works (!) but apparently is not the appropriate way to do things, and sendMessage should work anyway.

So, what is the incredibly obvious thing I'm missing? :-)

Here's the activity:

```
package org.foo.testapp;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                System.out.println("HANDLE: " + inputMessage.obj);
                // Looper.loop();  This doesn't seem to matter either way
            }
        };
    }

    public void startEverything(View v) {
        System.out.println("Button clicked");

        TestMessage tm = new TestMessage(mHandler);
        Thread tmthread = new Thread(tm);
        tmthread.start();
    }
}
```

Here's the thread sending messages:

```
package org.foo.testapp;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class TestMessage implements Runnable {    Handler mHandler;
    int foo;

    TestMessage(Handler inputHandler) {
        mHandler = inputHandler;
        foo = 0;
    }

    public void run()  {
        while(true) {
            foo = foo + 1;
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj = "SENDING " + foo;
            System.out.println("SENDING " + foo);
            //mHandler.sendMessage(msg);  this loses messages
            if(!mHandler.sendMessage(msg)) {
                System.out.println("Error sending!");
            }
            //mHandler.dispatchMessage(msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

..and here's the kind of output I get when I use sendMessage (exact output varies).

```
Button clicked
SENDING 1
HANDLE: SENDING 1
SENDING 2
HANDLE: SENDING 2
SENDING 3
HANDLE: SENDING 3
SENDING 4
HANDLE: SENDING 4
SENDING 5
SENDING 6
SENDING 7
SENDING 8
SENDING 9
SENDING 10
SENDING 11
SENDING 12
SENDING 13
SENDING 14
SENDING 15
SENDING 16
SENDING 17
SENDING 18
SENDING 19
SENDING 20
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with this exact code running on a Nexus 7 Lollipop emulator.

Comment: Interesting - I should have mentioned I am running this on a Nexus 5 5.0.1 emulator.  Let me try on the 7.  What OS level are you emulating at?  (I'm at API level 21, to be precise)

Comment: I am using the Genymotion emulator on Lollipop 5.0.0

Comment: Well, I think I've found it, and @corsair992, you gave me the clue.

I'm going to add a posting below explaining what I think is up -- if you do likewise, I'll credit you for the win.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found due to @corsair992.

The code above was running in the HAXM Intel emulator, Nexus-5, API Level 21, x86_64 (don't know if 64-bit is relevant, but let's assume for the moment it is).  I'm developing in Android Studio.

Prompted by @corsair992's comment, I ran the code in a Nexus-7 API Level 21 arm emulator.  Code behaved as you would expect, and as corsair saw.

Next, I created a Nexus-5 ARM emulator with the same specs.  Code ran correctly (no messages lost).

Back to the HAXM Intel emulator:  buggy code.

So, I'd guess the question I have now is:  is the HAXM emulator known to be buggy?  Could someone try on that emulator?

Comment: OK, I'll try this in the x86 ATOM System Image. I have the version with Google APIs downloaded but it's very buggy, and the launcher keeps crashing. I'll see if I have better luck on the standard version.

Comment: Last followup for the moment - the issue seems to be related to the _x64 emulator after all.  It looks like straight x86 works fine.

Comment: Well, the emulator is not even initializing completely for me, so it's definitely buggy :)

Comment: Apart from emulators, I see this behaviour on a real device (Nexus 5). Still don't know how to solve it.